# Homomorphism between direct products and quotients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove (G1 x G2)/(K1 x K2) is isomorphic to G1/K1 x G2/K2.

Attempt: First, we need to show a homomorphism exists, such that f : G1 x G2 → G1/K1 x G2/K2.

WHere (g1,g2) are pair elements in G1 x G2. And G1/K1 and G2/K2 are quotient groups. I have tried to define a homomorphism such that φ[(g1,g2)] = (g1,g2)(K1 x K2).

Please can anyone just help me define a correct homomorphism. I am not sure if this is correct. I have tried several, but are wrong.
Thank you

Comment: I assume that $K_{i}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{i}$. Check the
map $G_{1}\times G_{2}\rightarrow\left(G_{1}\times G_{1}\right)/\left(K_{1}\times K_{1}\right)$
prescribed by $\left(g_{1},g_{2}\right)\mapsto\left(g_{1}K_{1},g_{2}K_{2}\right)$.
Is it a grouphomomorphism? Is it surjective? If so, then what is its
kernel?

Comment: For (G1 x G1)/(K1 x K1) don't we need (G1 x G2)/(K2 x K2).

Comment: That was a typo, sorry: It must be $G_{1}\times G_{2}\rightarrow\left(G_{1}\times G_{2}\right)/\left(K_{1}\times K_{2}\right)$

Comment: Thank you it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the canonical projection maps $G\to G/K$ for normal subgroups $K$?

Do you know how to put maps $A\to B$, $C\to D$ together to get $A\times C\to B\times D$?

Comment: For the first part I am not sure. But for the second one do you mean define to homomorphisms functions. For example : Φ1[(g1,g2)] = g1K1 and Φ2[(g1,g2)] = g2K2. Then I do their direct products of the functions?

Comment: @user29043, Do you see that to define a function from the domain to the range, the argument to the function has to be an element of the domain? Can you see that (g1, g2) is not an element of (G1 X G2) / (K1 X K2)?